# Sony flash tools .tar installation on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, flash, sony

i am running **ubuntu 18.04** and i want to install the **sony flash tools** app in order to flash an xperia sm5303.

i found and downloaded on my desktop the following 2 files:

a) SP Flash Tool v5.1752 Linux
https://www.t-flash.net/download-sp-flash-tool-latest-version-windows-linux/

b) flashtool-0.9.25.0-linux
http://www.flashtool.net/downloads_linux.php

i extracted them from the original .tar folders but couldnot find a readme file in either case...i then opened a terminal and 
 'cd' ed to the directory and tried to

*./configure* 
and/or
*make*

but no luck...

[image]

any help on how to install the specific apps???
would appreciate detailed step by step instructions!

thanks community! )

Comment: Please edit your question and include links to the applications.

Comment: post your error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## SP Flash Tool v5.1752 Linux

You need to get `libpng12` as the first step:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
```

It seems that you do not need to compile anything here. It is binary release.

```
unzip "SP Flash Tool v5.1752 Linux.zip"
mv "SP Flash Tool v5.1752 Linux" "SP_Flash_Tool_v5.1752_Linux"
cd SP_Flash_Tool_v5.1752_Linux
chmod +x flash_tool
```

and run it with

```
./flash_tool
```

[image: SP Flash] and follow instruction for your device.

## FlashTool

It is binary release too. So you need to extract it and launch binary file.

```
7z x flashtool-0.9.25.0-linux.tar.7z
tar -xf flashtool-0.9.25.0-linux.tar
cd FlashTool
```

and run it with

```
sudo ./FlashTool
```

[image: FlashTool] and follow instruction for your device.

Comment: both ways worked just fine for me. thanx a lot!!!