# How to open flashtool Ubuntu 18.04 problem with the command

Tags: system-installation

What am I doing wrong? The program can not see the phone.

[image]

Comment: I'm doing everything like this topic https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075330/sony-flash-tools-tar-installation-on-ubuntu-18-04        and I managed to open flashtool but I can not open this second option

Comment: Could you please tell us your smartphone model that you are trying to flash? Different vendors and models require different tools.

Comment: Thank you for your help N0rbert my phone is sony xperia M4 E2303

Answer (score 0):

The flashtool needs direct access to `/dev/ttyACM0` if I am correct.

So either run with

`sudo ./flashtool`

or

`chmod 777 /dev/ttyACM0`

And be sure the ACM driver is not blacklisted in `/etc/modprobe.d/`.

Comment: Running `sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER` would be better to have access to `/dev/ttyACM0` by normal user.

Answer (score 0):

As your phone [is based on Qualcomm CPU](https://www-support-downloads.sonymobile.com/e2303/whitepaper_EN_e2303_e2306_e2353_xperia_m4_aqua.pdf), then you should use [FlashTool from Androxyde](http://www.flashtool.net/index.php) for it.

1. Download it as ["Full edition (0.9.25.0)"](http://www.flashtool.net/downloads_linux.php) (here I used [torrent-based download](http://www.flashtool.net/torrents/flashtool-0.9.25.0-linux.tar.7z.torrent))
2. Extract and launch downloaded tool:

   ```
   7z x flashtool-0.9.25.0-linux.tar.7z
   tar -xf flashtool-0.9.25.0-linux.tar
   cd FlashTool
   ```
3. run it with

   ```
   sudo ./FlashTool
   ```
4. follow instruction for your device.

Comment: I do not know what I'm doing wrong,, I Download the documents and I extract it. then I enter the command in the terminal and nothing